# OAuth with Office 365 SOAP returns "The audience claim value is invalid"

Tags: soap, outlook, office365, exchangewebservices

I have been trying to integrate Office 365 Exchange services using OAuth for a web app. We already have an integration for on premise and this integration works with Basic [username:password] authentication with https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx

**Authorization using:**
https://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&prompt=consent&client_id=[APP_ID]&redirect_uri=[URL]

**Getting token using:**
POST
https://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/token

Body:
grant_type=authorization_code&code=[Code]&redirect_url=[URL]&scope=https://outlook.office365.com/calendars.readwrite

I was able to get a token successfully.

Application Permissions I set up on Azure App Registration are:

**Microsoft Graph Permissions**
Read and write user and shared calendars
Read user and shared calendars
Send mail as a user
Read user calendars
Have full access to user calendars

**Office 365 Exchange Online Permissions**
Read user and shared calendars
Read and write user and shared calendars
Send mail as a user
Read user calendars
Read and write user calendars

With the token I acquire, I am trying to create an event using;
https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx

Header:

- POST /EWS/Exchange.asmx HTTP/1.1
- Host: outlook.office365.com
- client_request_id: [random_guid]
- User-Agent: APPName
- Authorization: Bearer [TOKEN]

Body:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" 
xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
<soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2016"/>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
<m:CreateItem SendMeetingInvitations="SendToAllAndSaveCopy">
    <m:Items>
        <t:CalendarItem>
            <t:Subject>Test Event</t:Subject>
            <t:Body BodyType="HTML">Test Body</t:Body>
            <t:Start>2018-11-17T08:00:00.000</t:Start>
            <t:End>2018-11-17T09:00:00.000</t:End>
            <t:StartTimeZone Id="Pacific Standard Time"/>
            <t:EndTimeZone Id="Pacific Standard Time"/>
        </t:CalendarItem>
    </m:Items>
</m:CreateItem>
```

This is the response I am getting with status code 401:

```
Server →Microsoft-IIS/10.0
request-id →b6d17647-5285-4c40-9087-3875958750b2
X-CalculatedFETarget →MWHPR1601CU001.internal.outlook.com
X-BackEndHttpStatus →401
X-BackEndHttpStatus →401
Set-Cookie →exchangecookie=947fe20a28e842068b3fe78a71b4e15b; path=/
X-FEProxyInfo →MWHPR1601CA0011.NAMPRD16.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM
X-CalculatedBETarget →MWHPR2001MB1823.namprd20.prod.outlook.com
X-RUM-Validated →1
x-ms-diagnostics →2000003;reason="The audience claim value is invalid 'aud'.";error_category="invalid_resource"
X-BeSku →Gen9
X-DiagInfo →MWHPR2001MB1823
X-BEServer →MWHPR2001MB1823
X-FEServer →MWHPR1601CA0011
X-FEServer →BYAPR05CA0077
X-Powered-By →ASP.NET
WWW-Authenticate →Bearer client_id="00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000", trusted_issuers="00000001-0000-0000-c000-000000000000@*", token_types="app_asserted_user_v1 service_asserted_app_v1", authorization_uri="https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize", error="invalid_token",Basic Realm="",Basic Realm="",Basic Realm=""
Date →Wed, 14 Nov 2018 22:07:28 GMT
Content-Length →0
```

I have been reading and making research for the last two days but could not find anything similar where other devs tried same integration.

Could you please advise?
Maybe there is someone who can explain what I am doing wrong.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With EWS you should be requesting a Scope of https://outlook.office365.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All or https://outlook.office365.com/full_access_as_app if your trying to use AppOnly tokens. The other constrained scopes aren't valid for EWS as its a bit of legacy API in this respect.

Comment: I have tried this but no luck. Still the same error. One thing I noticed, error suggests authorization_uri="https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize", error="invalid_token". But I try to Authorize the app "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_it>/oauth2/authorize".

Comment: It looks like your using the v1 endpoint ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison if so you shouldn't be using the scope as that would be invalid in v1 but rather use the resource=https://outlook.office365.com

Comment: Your last comment worked. Thank you so much. If you update your answer I will mark it as the solution.